# How to Display Two Javascript Functions with One Button Click

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I am currently finishing up a Web Development course and this week we are covering: Adding Javascript to your website. The scripts are easy to add and I have gotten everything to work, however, the purpose of the script and the site do not go together. One of the tasks is to add a button and onclick - the time and data are displayed. I get the intent here to demonstrate that you can add these elements to a page - but it does not make sense to me. So, I want to add the date and time in a way that it fits with the purpose of my site - which covers COVID information. Hence, what I am putting together is a button that when clicked will display the date and time (as required) and also display an embeded map from Our World In Data. This will meet the assignment requirements and have a logical purpose for displaying the time/date along with an update on COVID information.

Now, what I am finding out is that a div tag cannot have two IDs and that a function cannot have more than one element. However, there has to be a way that a button can display two things when clicked - right?

So, after two days at this - this is where I am at and any suggestions you may have are more than welcomed. Remember, I am learning here as I go and I do not have any education in Javascript at this time.

---

**Where I am at with two separate buttons:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Covid Status</h1><br>           
        <p>The following Button will display what the current COVID Status is around the world, according to Our World In Data.</p><br>
        <div id="Covid_stat"></div>
        <input type="button" value="Show Chart" onClick="covid();">
        <div id="Time"></div>
        <input type="button" value="Show Time" onClick="time();">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function Time() {
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = Date();
}
function Covid_stat(){
    document.getElementById('covid').innerHTML='<embed src="https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/positive-rate-daily-smoothed?year=latest&time=earliest..latest" loading="lazy" style="width: 100%; height: 600px; border: 0px none;"></embed>';
}
</script>
```

---

**What I am trying do via various online examples:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Covid Status</h1><br>           
        <p>The following Button will display what the current COVID Status is around the world, according to Our World In Data.</p><br>
        <button type="button" id="Show_Info">Show Information</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function Time() {
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = Date();
}
function Covid_stat(){
    document.getElementById('covid').innerHTML='<embed src="https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/positive-rate-daily-smoothed?year=latest&time=earliest..latest" loading="lazy" style="width: 100%; height: 600px; border: 0px none;"></embed>';
}
var showbtn = document.getElementById("Show_Info");
showbtn.addEventListener("click", Time);
showbtn.addEventListener("click", Covid_stat);
</script>
```

In advance, Thank You Very Much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I have been helpful.

```js
        function myFunc() {
            document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = Date();
            document.getElementById('covid').innerHTML = '<iframe src="https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/positive-rate-daily-smoothed?year=latest&time=earliest..latest" loading="lazy" style="width: 100%; height: 600px; border: 0px none;"></iframe>';
        }

        var showbtn = document.getElementById("Show_Info");
        showbtn.addEventListener("click", myFunc);
```

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Covid Status</h1><br>
            <p>The following Button will display what the current COVID Status is around the world, according to Our
                World In Data.</p><br>
            <button type="button" id="Show_Info">Show Information</button>
        </div>
        <div id="time"></div>
        <div id="covid"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: 54ka, Thank You! Yes, that answers it. I happened to find another way as well and came back to answer my own question and I saw yours - Awesome! The only thing we cannot do is use iframe - we can only embed items - do to security concerns. I am going to post what I found as well. Thank you again for such a fast respond. Now I need to figure out how to do a snippet like you did and close this question because it has been answered. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function that calls your other two functions when you click the button.

Comment: Sagichnicht04, Thank you very much. The terminology you provided led me to figure out the answer I was seeking. Thank you very-very much.